# Angular2 & MAMP integration

Tags: php, angular

I am currently using AngularCLI to generate an app for me. When starting npm serve is starts its own server. However, i need to integrate PHP / MAMP and thus it uses it's own web server.

What is the best way to link the two? Very little info on Google but I am probably not searching for the right terms.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, to host your app on a mamp-server you just need to:

```
ng build --prod
```

and then copy the files in the dist-folder to the root of your web-server.

But Im guessing that you then want to read and write from the database.

This is my recommendation:
**Dont put php-tags in your html, make web-services**

e.g. make php-scripts that get data from the database and outputs the as json, then use HTTP to get the data to your Angular-app.

Answer (score 0):

Add root url (hostname) into build js links in index.html,index.html not understand to .css .js files in build folder in hosting time.